# Custom column to find next next-best minimum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two custom columns, the first one is working and it finds the minimum text value, the next custom column I am struggling to write the correct code for, I need to find the next minimum text value not found in the first custom column

## CODE for 1st column (working)

```
ATTRIBUTE_IDENTIFIER_01 =
IF (
    'Customer Attributes'[ATTRIBUTE_COUNTBY_TID_Identifier] > 0,
    MIN ( 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute] ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

## CODE for 2nd column (not working need help)

```
ATTRIBUTE_IDENTIFIER_02 =
IF (
    'Customer Attributes'[ATTRIBUTE_COUNTBY_TID_Identifier] > 0
        AND ATTRIBUTE_IDENTIFIER_01 <> BLANK (),
    MIN ( 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute] )
        WHERE (
            MIN ( 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute] )
                <> 'Customer Attributes'[ATTRIBUTE_IDENTIFIER_01] )
        ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

I will be creating 10 of these `ATTRIBUTE_IDENTIFIER` columns and in each one, I need to make sure that I find the next minimum value. I am open to suggestions if there is a simplified way of achieving the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest ranking the `Attribute` values and then pulling whichever rank you want:

```
ATTRIBUTE_IDENTIFIER_02 =
VAR Attributes =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute] ),
        ALL ( 'Customer Attributes' ),
        'Customer Attributes'[ATTRIBUTE_COUNTBY_TID_Identifier] > 0
    )
VAR Ranked =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Attributes,
        "Rank", RANKX ( Attributes, [Attribute],, ASC, DENSE )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX ( FILTER ( Ranked, [Rank] = 2 ), [Attribute] )
```

The first variable `Attributes` is just a list of the `'Customer Attributes'[Attribute]` values that satisfy the condition `'CustomerAttributes'[ATTRIBUTE_COUNTBY_TID_Identifier] > 0`.

We take that list and a column to rank it alphabetically to get `Ranked`.

Then take the maximal (only) `Attribute` value from `Ranked` where the rank is what you want.